# How to validate a boolean in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app, I have a boolean in my Authors table. How do I validate how many times that boolean can be set to false?

---

The code I have now doesn't work correctly

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base

    validate :book_limit, :on => :update
      def book_limit
        if self.user.authors(:reload).count(:conditions => { :book => true }) >= 15
          errors.add(:base, "Exceeds book limit: Book 15/15")
        end
      end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :book_limit, :on => :update

  def book_limit
    if self.user.authors.where(book: true).count >= 15
      errors.add(:base, "Exceeds book limit: Book 15/15")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel tried to but SO makes it to where I have to wait 15 minutes before doing so..

Comment: ah, maybe. SO is very annoying sometimes ;)

Comment: Wait, everytime i remove a boolean thats at that limit, I still get the validation message, therefore can't remove it @henrikhodne

Comment: nvm, I just decided to hide the boolean after 15.. thanks again @henrikhodne